# Determinant of 2D non-positive second order partial differential operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations, differential-operators, determinants

If I have an ordinary second order differential operator the Gelfand-Yaglom method is often useful to calculate its (regularized) determinant. The great advantage is that one doesn't have to calculate all eigenvalues explicitly, the method gives the determinant directly.

If the operator is a partial differential operator and positive definite, zeta-function regularization is often useful. In the positive case Green function methods also apply.

Now what methods are available for a second order partial differential operator (let's say 2D for simplicity) which is not positive definite?